# Where does WPF's RichTextBox editor get it's spell checking from?

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, spell-checking

Does it use Microsoft Word's spellchecker?

Thank you.

Comment: the question 'why?' springs to mind...

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: What what?

Comment: Why do you need to know? What are you trying to do, what is your problem and what is your real question?

Comment: I'm just curious. The question is at the top of the page, please read it before commenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not part of Microsoft Word. They are part of WPF. It would be an inconvenience to developers to have a feature dependent on a Microsoft Word installation. Instead, it uses an embedded dictionary.

WPF4 [introduced](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2009/10/02/custom-dictionaries.aspx) functionality for custom dictionaries.

Comment: An "inconvenience" is putting it mildly.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what you need it for.

So here is a wild guess. You may want to check out: http://nhunspell.sourceforge.net/

NHunspell brings the spell checking, hyphenation and thesaurus to the Microsoft® .NET Framework. NHunspell is C# library and wraps native libraries for Hunspell, Hyphen and MyThes. One design goal of this library and wrapper is to keep the source code of the included libraries as unmodified as possible. New versions of the base libraries can therefore easily adopted to NHunspell.
 The integrated libraries are used in OpenOffice and they work with the dictionaries published on OpenOffice.org.