# Recommendation for WinForms Spell Checker

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, spell-checking

I have a WinForms application for editing text in a large RichTextBox control.

Can anyone suggest the easiest (and hopefully cheapest) way to add spell checking to the RichTextBox control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use [hosted content](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms) and place a WPF control that offers spell checking. For example the WPF RichTextBox has a property `SpellCheck` which you can enable.

Note that [WPF uses its own spellchecker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593754/where-does-wpfs-richtextbox-editor-get-its-spell-checking-from) and doesn't require Microsoft Office.

Comment: I didn't realize WPF has this feature. WPF is on my list of technologies to learn. I've never looked at hosting WPF content on a WinForm though. I'll have to play with that.